# Nutch : Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, solr, nutch

when I execute this commands line :

```
ahmed@ubuntu:~/apache-nutch-1.9/bin$ ./crawl seeds fir localhost:8983/solr 1
```

I got this errors Exception in the end of Execution:

```
Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:114)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:186)
```

Can I have please a Hand Help.